# What are the main differences between installing a module vs including it using its url?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, module, difference

What I want to understand is what are the main differences between;

```
<script src="module_url.js"></script>
```

vs

```
npm install module
```

Does one have any performance benefits? Or which one of those is better for separation of concerns? My question is specific to Node.js but answers for other platforms, frameworks, etc. are highly appreciated.

Comment: One difference is that in node you can't use modules with <script>, you have to install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use any NodeJS module, you have to do `npm install <module>`

Script includes is basically for client side loading i.e. UI code, as this approach reduces the load on the server (for serving the libraries). Usually libraries are hosted on `CDN` servers, which allows faster downloads at that geo-location.
Sometimes, the scripts might not be available as `CDN` and/or you might have custom version of the library script, in these cases you will want to use `bundlers` like `webpack` or `browserify` to serve your client libraries from Node backend-for-frontend or an web server.

Bundlers basically allows you to reduce the code size and faster serving. 
Ref: [JS Bundlers](https://medium.com/@ajmeyghani/javascript-bundlers-a-comparison-e63f01f2a364)

Comment: Thank you for clarification. However, if client is unable to fetch the code, can bundlers be used as a backup? Do they have integrated logic to do that or we need to write custom controller?

Comment: To cover the case of client's being unable to use `CDN` code, you have to use Bundling. You can use Node backend server to serve these files from Public folder. Check the link I have added in my answer, expressjs is serving static content from `public` directory

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing apples and oranges. They do completely different and unrelated things.

---

A script element…

> ```
> <script src="module_url.js"></script>
> ```

… tells a **web browser** to request some JS from a URL and execute it in the context of a webpage.

---

Using NPM to install a module…

```
npm install module
```

… tells npm to download the module, and its dependencies, and store them in a **Node.js** project.

Comment: You are absolutely right however I think my question is not clear. Let's say I want to include some front-end library like bootstrap. I could install its Node module or I could include it inside script tag. I may still be making wrong comparisons, but eventually both methods will work. This is the difference I want to compare

Comment: @AtakanAtamert — No. They won't. Installing a node module won't put it anywhere near the browser. You might install the node module, then look in the node_modules directory for the JS file, then make it available over a URL, and then load it with a `<script>` … but then you're just using a `<script>` element.